# How is library resolved via require

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, import, require

I'm using `npm` and have my libraries in `node-modules`.

When I use `import` or `require`, for example `import A from 'my_lib'`, somehow library gets resolved (something is imported from `my_lib`).

How does the library get resolved?

I think `index.js` file get's checked if it exists (similar to when I import from my custom folder with `./my_folder`, the `./my_folder/index.js` is checked)? What are the rules?

---

NOTE: Sometimes I use `webpack`, and I think in webpack there is `resolve.mainFiles` property with default value of `['index']` meaning if folder is specified it uses `index.js`.

But I'm using for example `react` library which doesn't have `index.js` in root folder and it still resolves properly.

---

Does the resolver look in package.json if the specified folder has one?

Comment: It should look for `my_lib/index.js` in your `node_modules`, or for `my_lib.js` if it is in your path. Are you running the code in plain node.js, or using something like webpack to deploy it in the browser?

Comment: I'm having both webpack case and node's require case. You mean it will search for either my_lib folder on the path or my_lib.js on the path. If it finds the folder it checks my_lib/index.js. But it seems there is more to just these two.